# Change the link URL in default RSS feeds

Tags: rss, feed

My wordpress feeds post item looks following:

```
<item>
   <title>Taste Trail – Lima and Cusco’s Best Eats</title>
   <link>
   http://example.com/taste-trail-lima-and-cuscos-best-eats/</link>
   <comments>http://example.com/taste-trail-lima-and-cuscos-best-eats/#comments</comments>
   <pubDate>Tue, 16 Apr 2013 03:24:37 +0000</pubDate>
   <dc:creator>anzprod</dc:creator>
   <guid isPermaLink="false">http://example.com/?p=717</guid>
   <description>
      <![CDATA[Data]]>
   </description>
   <wfw:commentRss>
      http://example.com/taste-trail-lima-and-cuscos-best-eats/feed/
   </wfw:commentRss>
   <slash:comments>0</slash:comments>
</item>
```

I want to change the URL of the post to something like

```
http://example.com/#!view/taste-trail-lima-and-cuscos-best-eats
```

Please help me with how to do this!

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? [You are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could filter `'the_permalink_rss'`:

```
add_filter( 'the_permalink_rss', 'wpse_96602_change_feed_item_url' );

function wpse_96602_change_feed_item_url( $url )
{
    $parts = parse_url( $url );

    return $parts['scheme'] . '://' . $parts['host'] . '/#!view' . $parts['path'];
}
```

But … I strongly recommend not to do that. [Hash-bangs will break your web site](http://isolani.co.uk/blog/javascript/BreakingTheWebWithHashBangs).